# Unit test constructor that uses My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

I have a constructor that looks like this:

Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        ws.Url = My.Settings.WebServiceURL
 End Sub

(ws is private)

Is there any point in unit testing this?

The class did not previously have this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only constructor for the class? If so, then you test it every time you test the class, and a separate test is unnecessary. If you had written a separate test, you would have refactored it into the others after the first success.

Comment: Well, the class did not have any constructors before. Two were added. All they do is to call the base and setting the url.

MyBase.New(formatter)
ws.Url = My.Settings.WebServiceUrl